# How can I migrate this next.js code from v3 to v4 for the OpenAI API?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, openai-api

This is my code:

```
'use client';

import axios from "axios";
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";
import {useState} from 'react';
import * as z from "zod";
import {ChatCompletionRequestMessage} from 'openai';
import {Loader} from '@/components/loader';


import {Heading} from '@/components/heading';
import {MessageSquare} from 'lucide-react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
import {formSchema} from './constant';
import {zodResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {Form, FormField, FormItem, FormControl} from '@/components/ui/form';
import {Input} from '@/components/ui/input';
import {Button} from '@/components/ui/button';
import {Empty} from '@/components/empty';
import { UserAvatar } from "@/components/UserAvatar";
import { BotAvatar } from "@/components/bot-avatar";

const ConversationPage =() => {
    const [messages, setMessages] =useState<ChatCompletionRequestMessage[]>([]);
    const router = useRouter();
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues:{
            prompt:""
        }
    });
    const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;
    const onSubmit = async(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
        try {
            const userMessage: ChatCompletionRequestMessage = {
                role:'user',
                content: values.prompt,
            };
            const newMessages = [...messages, userMessage];

            const response = await axios.post('/api/conversation',{
                messages: newMessages,
            });

            setMessages((current)) => [...current, userMessage, response.data]);
            form.reset();
        } catch (error:any){
            // TODO: Open Pro Modal
            console.log(error);
        } finally{
            router.refresh();
        };

    };


    return(
        <div>
            <Heading
                title= "Conversation"
                description = "Our most advanced conversation model."
                icon = {MessageSquare}
                iconColor= 'text-violet-500'
                bgColor='bg-violet-500/10'
            />
            <div className='px-4 lg:px-8'>
                <div>
                    <Form{...form}>
                        <form 
                        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                        className="
                        rounded-lg
                        border
                        w-full
                        p-4
                        px-3
                        md:px-6
                        focus-within:shadow-sm
                        grid
                        grid-cols-12
                        gap-2"
                        >
                            <FormField
                               name='prompt'
                               render ={({field}) =>(
                                <FormItem className='col-span-12 lg:col-span-10'>
                                    <FormControl className="m-0 p-0">
                                        <Input className = 'border-0 outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent'
                                        disabled= {isLoading}
                                        placeholder = 'How do I calculate the radius of a circle?'
                                        {...field}
                                        />
                                    </FormControl>
                                </FormItem>
                               )}  

                            />
                            <Button className= "col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full" disabled={isLoading}>
                               Generate 
                            </Button>
                        </form>
                    </Form>
                </div>
                <div className = 'space-y-4 mt-4'>
                    {isLoading && (
                        <div className = 'p-8 rounded-lg w-full flex items-center justify-center bg-muted'>
                            <Loader/>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    {messages.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
                        <Empty label='No conversation started.'/>
                    )}
                    <div className='flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4'>
                        {messages.map(message)=>(
                            <div 
                                key={message.content}
                                className={cn(
                                    "p-8 w-full flex items-start gap-x-8 rounded-lg"
                                    message.role === 'user'? 'bg-white border border-black/10' : 'bg-muted'
                                )}
                            >
                                {message.role === 'user'? <UserAvatar/>: <BotAvatar/>}
                                <p className='text-sm'>
                                    {message.content}
                                </p>
                                

                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default ConversationPage;
```

I tried using the official migration guide from OpenAI. While that helped me change `ChatCompletionsRequestMessage` to

`const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({ model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", messages: [userMessage], });`

as well as the import errors such as importing OpenAI like this:
`import OpenAI from "openai"; const openai = new OpenAI();`
I was still running into problems with this snippet:

```
const ConversationPage =() => {
    const [messages, setMessages] =useState<ChatCompletionRequestMessage[]>([]);
    const router = useRouter();
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues:{
            prompt:""
        }
    });
```

I am new to using React so I thought to post the original snippet so that someone can outline all the specific changes I should make. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.